# == operator for primitive data types

Tags: java, equals, primitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Does the toString(), ==, equals() object methods work differently or similarly on reference and primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586223/how-does-the-tostring-equals-object-methods-work-differently-or-similarl)

I am trying to understand the difference between == and equals to operator in Java.
e.g. == will check if it is the same object while equals will compare the value of the object ... Then why do we use == for comparing primitive data types like int. 
Because if I have

```
   int i =7; //and 
   int j = 6.
```

They are not the same object and not the same memory address in stack. Or does the == behaves differently for primitives comparison.??

Comment: `==` is an operator and `equals` is a method of which the implementation can be modified. Also you should be aware of something that is called interning: http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Answer (score 9):

Actually, == behaves identically for all variables: it tests whether the values of those variables are equal. In the case of `Object obj`, `obj` is a *reference* to an object. Since `==` tests whether two object references have the same value, it is testing whether they refer to the identical object (i.e., that the references are equal).

Comment: Well, not *quite* the same. Two `double` variables with the bit pattern for "not a number" have identical bit patterns, but will still compare not-equal. That's an edge case though, fortunately :)

Comment: I always knew my NaN was unique (excuse the pun). More seriously, what is the intent behind this if this was done by design?

Comment: For anyone wondering, found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145443/why-is-double-nan-not-equal-to-itself) as well as this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471296/how-can-while-i-i-be-a-non-infinite-loop-in-a-single-threaded-applicatio) and this [curiosity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408569/why-does-double-nan-equal-itself-when-wrapped-in-a-double-instance).

Comment: @Jon - Did I mention bit patterns? I agree that the case of NaN is unusual, but I stand by what I said. According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.1), Java uses the IEEE 754 rules for floating point equality tests. Those rules say that two NaN values are not equal, despite having identical bit patterns. Another edge case is +0.0 and -0.0, which have different bit patterns but nevertheless test equal.

Comment: @Ted: No, you didn't mention bit patterns - but you did say `==` behaves *identically* for all variables, and I think it's worth highlighting these oddities. Saying "it tests whether the values of those variables are equal" but not saying what "equal" means is really just punting the meaning on one step.

Comment: @Jon - Touché. For those who are interested in the gory details, I recommend the somewhat old but still excellent article by Thomas Wang: [Java Floating-Point Number Intricacies](http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`==` intuitively work differently on primitive types. Its just that way in the language.

If you think about it in C++ terms, references are pointers and `==` does pointer comparison.

```
int* myPtr1 = new int(5);
int* myPtr2 = new int(6);

myPtr1 == myPtr2;
```

Comment: `==` works the same for object references as it does for any other variable; it's just testing whether the references are equal.