# "letter finder" code to find the number of letters in a word

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lettercounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lettercounter = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence > ");
        String sentence = lettercounter.nextLine();

        int length = sentence.length();

        System.out.println("what letter do you seek? > ");
        String letters = lettercounter.nextLine();

        char letter = letters.charAt(0);
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
            char digit = sentence.charAt(i);
            if (Character.toString(digit).matches(Character.toString(letter))) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of '" + letter + "'s found >" + counter + "");
    }
}
```

whats wrong with the code?? i tried doing this but there seems to be an error when i run it: it says
xception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at lettercounter.main(lettercounter.java:15)

Comment: `i<length+1` should be `i<length`.

Comment: for some reason that seems to have solved the error ?

Comment: Also, you can just use `digit == letter`, instead of `Character.toString(digit).matches(Character.toString(letter))`

Comment: "hat seems to have solved the error " Huh. Almost like I suggested it for a reason :)

Comment: `matches` expects a regex. Try finding `+` or `(`...

Comment: Andy turner solved it :D

Comment: but why does it come up with the error that i cant compare string and char when i use == and .equals

Comment: You don't compare two `String`s via `==`, but you can compare two `char`s, since the latter is primitive, whereas the former is not. Perhaps refer to something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097886/operator-for-primitive-data-types for more info.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

`i<length+1` should be `i<length`.

This fixes the problem because there are only `length` characters in the string, accessible via `sentence.charAt(0)` up to `sentence.charAt(length - 1)`. You are trying to access one more character - `sentence.charAt(length)`.