# NaN Constant Magic in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Double.NaN==Double.NaN return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false)

**NaN** = "NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number is also undefined.

I was trying to use NaN Constant in Java

```
public class NaNDemo {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        double x = Double.NaN;
        double y = Double.NaN;

        System.out.println((x == y));
        System.out.println("x=" + x);
        System.out.println("y=" + y);
    }
}
```

Output

```
false
x=NaN
y=NaN
```

So why x==y is false ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/471314/751634

Comment: Or more directly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false.

Comment: Thanks @ jenoosia, This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is a concept, not a value or a number.  Since that concept can represent multiple non-real-number values (imaginary, 0/0, etc) it doesn't make sense to say that any particular NaN is equal to any other NaN.

Similarly you can't say that [`Double::NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY) equals itself, since infinity is not a number either.

Answer (score 1):

**The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN.**

[JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) sayes about NaN:

> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= return false if either or both operands are NaN (§15.20.1).
> - The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN.
> - In particular, (x=y) will be false if x or y is NaN.
> - The inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN    (§15.21.1).
>
> In particular, x!=x is true if and only if x is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Two `NaN` values cannot be equal to each other.. You don't know what undefined value they represent.. And also you don't know how they are represented..

As quoted in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) -

> the special number `NaN (not-a-number)` is unordered and has the
>   following characters:
>
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= always return false if either or both operands are NaN.
> - The equality operator == returns false if either operand is NaN.
> - The inequality operator != returns true if either operand is NaN .

If you define them like this: -

```
    Double a = new Double(Double.NaN);
    Double b = new Double(Double.NaN);

    if (a == b) {
        System.out.println("true");   /** You will get true **/
    }
```

Comment: this is not really right,  It is equivalent to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L).

Comment: @MeNoMore.. For which part you are saying this.. I guess for the second line -> You don't know what undefined value they represent..  May be you are right, because I'm not sure about this..

Comment: I meant the representation part too -> "you don't know how they are represented". you may not now hat leaded to the NaN, but Java declares their value and you can show them you will get NaN, which is their representation.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks MeNoMore.. Never faced `NaN` Face-to-Face before.. So, don't know many things about it..

Comment: -1: you should specify the source if you take something from that source. The description is taken from the [Java SE Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)

Comment: @PrakashK.. Sorry forgot that.. Added the source..

Comment: @PrakashK: Are you removing your -1 after he mentioned the source?

Comment: @Rohit Jain Me niether :) i just read it in the JSL as i answered this question thats why i know it. +1

Comment: @MeNoMore.. HaHa :) .. Thanks - for supporting a +1 Vote..

Comment: @MeNoMore Should I not remove it?

Comment: this is really old I know but I'm pretty shocked: how could ever two instances of ```Double``` initialized with ```new``` keyword and then compared to each other using ```==``` be ```true```??? -1 for this

Answer (score 0):

NaN - not-a-number doesnt make any sense  with when doing a operation with NAN number.so cant equal.